# Неверное отображение русских символов

Tags: кодировка, java

Возникла необходимость работы через консоль с русским буквами. Код такой:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"cp866");
System.setProperty("console.encoding","cp866");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
ps.println("Введите условия задачи");
String taskText=sc.nextLine();
ps.println("Мы получили текст: "+taskText);
```

В результате у меня получается примерно следующее:

```
Введите условия задачи
на дворе трава, на траве дрова12
Мы получили текст: ?? ????? ?????, ?? ????? ?????12
```

С кодировками экспериментировал, не помогло.

Comment: не в eclipse'овской консоли ли у вас проблемы?

Comment: Нет, в  Netbeans. И нет, вариант с кодировкой в UTF-8 ничего не изменил. Так и было в начале

Comment: @Solorad Примените версию конструктора `Scanner()` без кодовой страницы

Comment: Какая версия нетбинса? И какая ос?

Answer (score 12):

Раз вопрос всплыл, отвечу на него.

Ваша проблема в том, что "консоль" Netbeans - и консоль ОС - это немного разные вещи. В частности, у них отличаются используемые кодировки. Оптимальным было бы получение текущей кодировки консоли через Console API - но Java такого не предоставляет. Поэтому надо получить информацию о консольной кодировке другим способом. К примеру, через свойство `console.encoding`.

### Способ 1

Для начала, установка свойства `console.encoding` в предопределенное значение ничего не дает. Это свойство попросту никем не читается. Вместо того, чтобы ставить его в `cp866`, следовало бы, напротив, прочитать из него значение.

```
String encoding = System.getProperty("console.encoding", "utf-8");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, encoding);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, encoding);
```

Таким образом, вместо того, чтобы ожидать ввода в `cp866`, программа позволяет запустившему ее указать любую кодировку (`utf-8` - это кодировка по умолчанию. Замените ее на ту, которую использует консоль NetBeans). Запускать программу надо будет как-то так:

```
java -Dconsole.encoding=cp866 ...
```

На первый взгляд, такой способ запуска кажется сложным. Но обычно для запуска "серьезных" программ на Java всегда используется некоторый пакетный файл. Что мешает дописать этот ключ в него?

И не забывайте, консоль в Windows может оказаться в любой кодировке! К примеру, некоторые программы, такие как `reg.exe`, умеют работать с консолью только в `windows-1251`. Умение выводить в любой кодировке может пригодиться.

```
chcp 1251
reg ...

java -Dconsole.encoding=windows-1251 ...
```

### Способ 2

Если уже заговорили про пакетные файлы, то есть более простой способ, хотя и не такой мощный. Можно просто сменить кодировку консоли на нужную перед запуском программы:

```
chcp 1251
java ...
```

Вот номера кодовых страниц Windows, которые могут пригодиться:

- 866 - cp866
- 1251 - windows-1251
- 65001 - кодировка utf-8
- 1200 - двухбайтовая кодировка utf-16

### PS

Помните, что `System.in` и `System.out`, как правило, всегда должны быть в одной и той же кодировке. У вас в исходной программе сканер читал из `System.in` в кодировке `cp866` - а принтер выводил в `System.out` в кодировке по умолчанию. Такое несоответствие - тоже источник ошибок. Никогда так не делайте.

Answer (score 1):

Измените кодировку на UTF-8:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in,"utf-8");
System.setProperty("console.encoding","utf-8");
...
```

Отметьте, что кодировка UTF-8 используется по умолчанию. Можно просто писать так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
ps.println("Введите условия задачи");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

В консоли Windows 10 у меня заработало так:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 "D:\project\Program.java"
```