# На что влияет charset?

Tags: java, android

Я получаю файл вот кусок функции

```
while ((bytesRead = is.read(data)) > 0) {
                    try {
                        sb.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, charset));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.e(MY_LOG, "Invalid charset: " + e);
                        //Append without charset (uses system's default charset)
                        sb.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
                    }
                }
```

И у меня всегда попадает в блок `catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)` . Но файл записывается и все нормально...

Что означает этот charset? Я так понял это кодировка...

Но насколько страшно, что я записываю без нее?

Вот кстати метод который получает эту кодировку

```
String[] values = conn.getContentType().split(";");
    String charset = "";
    for (String value : values) {
        value = value.trim();
        if (value.toLowerCase().startsWith("charset=")) {
            charset = value.substring("charset=".length());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Я так понял, что если сервер передал мне файл с кодировкой, то я ее прочитываю и записываю файл с той же кодировкой...

Comment: что находится в `charset` перед вызовом `sb.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead, charset));`?

Comment: @metalurgus Ничего, там дефолтное значение `String charset = "";` Я так понимаю потому, что сервер не передает `charset` ... Может такое быть?

Comment: ну, посмотрите тогда, что находится в `conn.getContentType()`. Вам виднее, может ли ваш сервер не отдавать чарсет.

Comment: @metalurgus Вообще при получении `String[] values` содержит только первую ячейку со значением `application/text` ...

Comment: @metalurgus так это нормально, что не содержится чарсет? Это на что то влияет?

Comment: чарсет не является обязательным. Но его отсутстсвие теоретически может привести к проблемам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что означает этот charset? Я так понял это кодировка...

Вы правильно поняли что `charset` отвечает за то как раскодировать последовательность байтов в символы. В общем случае, из одного и того же же байт массива используя разные кодировки, вы получите разные строки. 
Вот, кстати, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153328/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) проблеммы при использовании неверной кодировки.

> Но насколько страшно, что я записываю без нее?

На столько-же на сколько страшно что в результате ваш текст будет состоять например из одних `?` - символ которым в некотрых кодировках заменяются все символы отсутствующие в кодировке.

> Но файл записывается и все нормально...

Скорее всего ваша система использует windows-1251 которая знает русские и аеглийские символы так что ваш файл раскодируется корректно. Но это скорее совпадение. Ваш код вряд ли будет работать для файла с китайскими символами.

Вот еще: получить charset по умолчанию для вашей JVM можно если выполнить

```
Charset.defaultCharset()
```

Answer (score 0):

Установите дефолтное значение `charset = "UTF-8";`, если сервер передаст этот параметр, то переменной `charset` установится принято значение