# Странный результат при выполнении программы

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Ege3632
{
    //private static String[] strValues = new String[27];
    private static String[] strValues =
            {"один","два","три","четыре","пять","шесть","семь","восемь","девять",
                    "одиннадцать","двенадцать","тринадцать","четырнадцать","пятнадцать",
                    "шестнадцать","семнадцать","восемнадцать","девятнадцать",
                    "десять","двадцать","тридцать","сорок","пятьдесят","шестьдесят",
                    "семьдесят","восемьдесят","девяноста"};
```

`public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    //  strValues[i] = reader.readLine();
    int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    String[] b = new String[N];
    int sum = 0;
    int j;
    for(int i =0; i < N; i++)
        b[i] = reader.readLine();
    for(int i =0; i< N; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(b[i].charAt(j)!=' ' && j!=(b[i].length()-1))
            j++;
        if(b[i].charAt(j)==' ')
        {
            int num1=getNumValue(b[i].substring(0,j));
            int num2=getNumValue(b[i].substring(j+1,b[i].length()));
            if(num1!=0 && num2!=0) sum+=num1+num2;
        } else if(getNumValue(b[i])!=0) sum+=getNumValue(b[i]);

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

private static int getNumValue(String strValue)
{
    int[] numValues={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
            11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
            10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    int j;
    for(int i =0; i < strValues.length; i++)
    {
        if(strValue.length()==strValues[i].length())
        {
            j =0;
            while(j<strValue.length() &&
                    strValue.charAt(j)==strValues[i].charAt(j))
                j++;
            if(j==strValue.length())return numValues[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}`

Как было задумано, программа должна выводить сумму введенных текстом чисел (числа в сумме от 1 до 99) при вводе сначала числа N (кол-во строк с числами), потом N строк с этими числами. То есть:

### Ввод:

- 2
- тридцать
- двадцать один

### Вывод:

- 51

Если я выполняю программу через IntelliJ IDEA, все работает нормально так, как задумано. Однако, если выполняю через консоль командами, при вводе любых символов, программа выдает 0. Не знаю, в чем дело. jdk использовал одной и той же версии из той же папки и при консольном выполнении, и в intellij idea.

---

Вот что показывает консоль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что с кодировкой? Попробуйте в массиве заменить "один" на "one" и прогнать тесты.

Comment: Почитайте здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153328/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: Попробовал сменить кодировку консоли на ту же, в которой записан файл кода - на utf-8. при выполнении программы в консоли теперь возвращает NullPointerException в 28-й строке. тяжко, ох как тяжко. хотя intellij idea данный код выполняет, и на NPE не жалуется