# Ошибка из-за кодировки в регулярном выражении

Tags: java, intellij-idea, кодировка

Сначала у меня была проблема из-за того, что после перезаписи текстовый файл автоматически изменял кодировку с windows -1251 на UTF-8, что увеличивало вес в два раза. Изменила настройки в IDEA , которые это делали автоматически.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но сейчас выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 7
>   ^([^Рђ-РЇР°-СЏa-zA-Z]+)
>          ^
>       at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2027)
>       at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2826)
>       at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2714)
>       at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern

Код программы:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestAndDelete{
    public static void main (String[] args){
    TestAndDelete a = new TestAndDelete();
    a.delete();
    }



    void delete (){
        Pattern foundWord=Pattern.compile("^([^А-Яа-яa-zA-Z]+)");
        File file=new File("ss.txt");

        try{
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "windows-1251"));

            String   line;
            StringBuilder ss=new StringBuilder();
            // ^([^А-Яа-яa-zA-Z]+)(\n)
            while ( (line=br.readLine())!=null ){

                if ( foundWord.matcher(line).find() ){
                    System.out.println("--- "+line);
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println(line);

            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

То, что внутри файла:

```
549785490 %+&#%\:&+#-#&+:\-



eeeee
htht
выаыва
```

Comment: Разве? Просто у меня получалось запускать через windows-1251, и он читал и перезаписывал без увеличения. Вот только теперь, когда я использую русские буквы в регулярном выражении, то он начинает выдавать ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас в коде нет никакой перезаписи файла. Есть вывод данных в консоль производится в кодировке консоли. Обычно это либо UTF-8, либо cp866. Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428042/221228). Если вам нужно записывать данные в файл в определенной кодировке, то и записывайте в файл с указанием кодировки

   ```
   Writer wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "windows-1251"));
   ```

2. То, что вы изменили в настройках IDEA - это кодировка **исходного** кода программы. И именно из-за этого у вас не может распарсится регулярное выражение, которое записано в строке. Не исключено, что само выражение повредилось при перекодировке

Comment: Печально, если я поставлю UTF-8 в настройках, то это сработает, но он его перекодирует и увеличит размер файла в два раза. 
Как я понимаю, параметр после file - это кодировка считывания, а можно ли как-то указать кодировку записи? 
Тогда бы можно было перекодировать в UTF-8 , выполнить действия и перекодировать снова в windows-1251, а после записать

Comment: Нашла, как менять напрямую. Спасибо за помощь